# Is there an advantage to Bootstrap placing global properties on body instead of html?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap 4 put global settings into a `body` element. This was also clearly stated in the documentation.

> #### [Page defaults](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/content/reboot/#page-defaults)
>
> The `<body>` also sets a global `font-family`, `line-height`, and `text-align`. This is inherited later by some form elements to prevent font inconsistencies.

In practice, `font-family`, `line-height`, and `text-align` can also be placed on the `html` element.

> #### [15.3 Font family: the 'font-family' property](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#propdef-font-family)
>
> 'font-family'
>
> - Initial:      depends on user agent
> - **Applies to:     all elements**
> - Inherited:     yes

Is there any advantage in selecting the `body` element when comparing the `html` and `body` elements in Bootstrap?

Comment: Sure you can put a line-height property on the html element, but why would you? If you need a certain line-height somewhere in the document that is not inside the body, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: There's no advantage. But it makes a lot more sense to be on `<body>` as it's the rendered part of the `<html>` and those properties refer to rendering. Now, even though they made the logical choice between the two, there are still people asking: *"Why didn't they choose the other?"*. Imagine how many would have asked: *"Why did they put them on `<html>`? 'Cause it's only the `<body>` that's rendered!"* if they did place those rules on `<html>`...